# How can I create a shared /home dir across my Amazon EC2 servers

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have a cluster of EC2 servers spun up with Ubuntu 12.04. This will be a dev environment where several developers will be ssh-ing in. I would like to set it up where the /home directory is shared across all 4 of these servers. I want to do this to A) ease the deployment of the servers, and B) make it easier on the devs so that everything in their homedir is available to them on all servers.

I have seen this done in the past with a NetApp network attached drive, but I can't seem to figure out how to create the equivalent using AWS components.

Does anyone have an idea of how I can create this same setup using Amazon services?

Comment: FWIW: Given the complexities involved in managing all the hosts/ports with access to NFS in a secure way, I prefer to run NFS in a private subnet of an EC2 Virtual Private Cloud. This way you are protected from connections from the outside world, and it makes it a lot easier to manage an internal security group that allows access to the required ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably need to have a server host an NFS share to store the home directories. I'd try out what this guy has done in his answer https://serverfault.com/questions/19323/is-it-feasible-to-have-home-folder-hosted-with-nfs.